# How to load an Assembly in a separate AppDomain and NOT default domain

Tags: c#, load, .net-assembly, appdomain, gettype

I've been searching for the past few days how to load an assembly in a separate app domain than the default one and I can't find an answer on how to do so. I will briefly explain the majority of things I have tried.

1. I have used CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap and this works....Mostly but there are 2 problems with this method. The first problem is that when I call `newDomain.GetAssemblies()` I get a FileNotFoundException and the only way to resolve this exception is to implement `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`. The problem with this is that it loads the assembly into the default domain, meaning I can't unload the Assembly. The Second problem is that I have a base abstract class in the running assembly called Task and I have child classes in other assemblies that derive from Task. When I call 
   `var obj = newDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(param1, param2)` it returns me a MarshalByRefObject (which it should) but when I cast it to the abstract class: 
   `var obj = (Task)newDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(param1, param2)`, the type of obj is "Task". 
   Now I know that it's an instance of ChildTask but it says that the type is Task and I need the type to be ChildTask but I can't convert it to ChildTask without loading the assembly into the Default Domain.
2. I have created a Proxy class that inherits from MarshalByRefObject and loaded the Assembly inside the Proxy class (as many of the answers on this topic suggest) but all it does is load the assembly into the default domain and not the created one. Therefore not allowing me to unload it once I'm finished with it.
3. I have used `newDomain.DoCallback(CallbackMethod)` in order to load an assembly without my new appdomain. The problem is that once the method has finished executing, the changes done in the Callback method have no effect on the Default Domain for example:

   ```
   public void DoSomething()
   {
       newDomain.DoCallback(CallbackMethod)
       Type type = newDomain.GetData("TYPE") // This returns null (as if nothing happened in     CallbackMethod)
   }

   public void CallbackMethod()
   {
       newDomain.SetData("TYPE", newDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(param1,   param2).GetType())
   } // At this point "TYPE" will be set to ChildTask
   ```

This makes sense because they are in separate domains so changes in one domain shouldn't effect another domain. I don't know how to allow them to interact with each other so that I can get a set value from CallbackMethod()

4. I have used `newDomain.Load()` (even though it's deprecated) and I get a FileNotFoundException even while using AppDomainSetup
5. I have tried using Serialization but I keep getting a bunch of serialization exceptions saying that a Type can't be resolved, etc and the only way to fix these exceptions is to using Assembly Resolve which loads the assembly into the Default Domain.

Is there something I'm missing? All I really want to do is be able to load an assembly into a new appdomain and get a type from that assembly, but it seems that I can't load assemblies unless they're loaded into the Default Domain. Is it possible to do this? Or will I just have to find a workaround?

Comment: There is not much you can do short of drawing on paper two big boxes marked "main AppDomain" and "new AppDomain", and draw whatever object you want to see in each. Don't mark either "current" because it completely depend on where code runs at particular moment... After starring for a while you may realize that what you want requires loading assembly to both domains or if you listening for events in domain you don't want to... Note that "type" belongs to "assembly" so you can't get type without one...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did think about it and logically what you're saying makes sense. So basically it's impossible to load and unload an assembly if you want to use something from that assembly.

Comment: If you want to see it in *both* domain - yes. Normally you would run all inspection/manipulation code in "new AppDomain" and return result to your main AppDomain in some form that does not involve types from that newly loaded assembly (i.e. interface implemented by type in assembly or just plain object/value in case of checking "is there class in this assembly that implements this interface).

Comment: So I would have no choice but to implement point #1. *sigh* Alright I'll have to use a workaround. Thanks for your help!